# Invalid AES key length: 12 bytes in java

Tags: java, encryption, aes, public-key-encryption

As per given steps, I have performed encryption but am getting an error.

1. Generate a 16-digit random number (session key). Say `RANDOMNO`.
   `RANDOMNO = 1111222233334444`
2. Encrypt `RANDOMNO` using RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding and encode using Base64. Say `ENCR_KEY`.
   `ENCR_KEY = B64Encode(RSA/ECB/PKCS1Encryption(RANDOMNO,ICICIPubKey.cer))`
3. Perform AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encryption on request payload using `RANDOMNO` as key and ivinitialization vector. Say `ENCR_DATA`.
   `ENCR_DATA = B64Encode(AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding(REQUEST_DATA, RANDOMNO, IV))`
4. Now the client may choose to send IV in request from one of the two options below.
   Send Base64 Encoded IV in “iv” tag.

```
  public  byte[] generateRandomBytes() {
          SecureRandom ng=new SecureRandom();
          byte[] randomBytes=new byte[16];
          ng.nextBytes(randomBytes);
          return randomBytes;
        }

//new method for encryption -we need to check
 public  String encryptRandomKeyWithCertificate(byte[] randomNumber) throws BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, FileNotFoundException, CertificateException {

    //step2: encrypt the random number with certificate
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("D:\\cedge_uat\\ICICIUATpubliccert.cer");
    CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) f.generateCertificate(fin);
    PublicKey publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(randomNumber);
    String encodedData = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherData);
    return encodedData;
}

public  String encryptRequestWithKey(String text, byte[] randomNumber) throws Exception {

    //step3: encrypt the requestString with randomkeyEncrypted
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(randomNumber, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec,ivSpec);
    byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
    // BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    //return encoder.encode(cipherData).replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "");
    String encodedData = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherData);
    return encodedData;
}

      
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    String requestString = "CORP_USER=";
    byte[] randomNumber;
    String encryptedKey;
    try {
        randomNumber=encryption.generateRandomBytes();
        encryptedKey = encryption.encryptRandomKeyWithCertificate(randomNumber);
        String encryptedData =encryption.encryptRequestWithKey(requestString,randomNumber);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: please help me, as per steps, i have done encryption but getting error. but why im getting this error

Comment: Using the string representation of a number is a terrible choice for a key. And your random number may not have 16 digits. Generate random bytes instead and use a PRNG such as SecureRandom, not Math.Random.

Comment: now i changed the above line like this SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(randomNumber.getBytes(), "AES");
    now encrypting done but while accessing the url 401 unauthorized, which side is mistake.client or server

Comment: can you help me please

Comment: As already written by @Marc you are still using a string for the AES-key Secondly: you still generate your key with Math.random and not with SecureRandom. Third: you are using a static initialization vector (filled with 16 x00) that makes the complete encryption **UNSECURE**. Before begging for help please correct your code and edit your question, thanks.

Comment: @michael, im beginner of developing the application. third:Instead of initaliazation vector what i have to do for this.Second: i checked secure random ,i have to pass same number for step 2 & step 3.how can i achieve that.  first, as you said im using aes-key so what i should use. Can you guide me please

Comment: I have changed  now secure random number.  Now what else i have to change

Comment: As you edited your code - does your program run as expected or do you receive some new error?

Comment: the key file start with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- –

Comment: Decrypt encryptedKey using algo (RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding) and Client’s private key.
I have the RSA private key in .key extension t but I have no idea how to decrypt with that key.Can you suggest any code how to acheive this

Comment: You have completely changed the question. Please revert the question to your original question about AES key sizes.  If you want to ask about using RSA ... ask a new question.

Comment: I have created the new question, if possible can you check and suggestion solution:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64007024/how-to-decrypt-the-message-using-private-key-rsa-algorithm-in-java

Comment: @StephenC As per above code, while decrypting the request ,first 16 digits is not receving.. they are saying the add the 16digits iv with request string. can you help me

Comment: No I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Wikipedia page on [AES encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), an AES key can be 128, 192 or 256 bits; i.e. 16, 24 or 32 bytes.

You are supplying a key whose size depends on the "random" number string you are generating.  It looks like it will be between 1 and 19 digits plus a possible sign.  When you call `getBytes()` on that string, you will get a byte array with anywhere between 1 and 20 bytes.  That is typically NOT one of the acceptable key sizes for AES.

What you should do is use `SecureRandom.nextBytes(byte[])` and supply a byte array of one of the three acceptable key sizes for AES.

Comment: the key file start with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: Decrypt encryptedKey using algo (RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding) and Client’s private key.
I have the RSA private key in .key extension t but I have no idea how to decrypt with that key.Can you suggest any code how to acheive this

Comment: You have completely changed the question.  Please revert the question to your **original** question about AES key sizes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64007024/how-to-decrypt-the-message-using-private-key-rsa-algorithm-in-java.

Comment: I have created new question ,can you check and suggest solution

Comment: @rathibha.: Kindly accept the answer of Stephen C as it is the correct one regarding your question, thanks.