# How to decrypt the message using private key -RSA algorithm in java

Tags: java, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key, encryption-asymmetric

As I'm generating the encrypted string using `.cer` file but unable to do decryption.

for decryption I have a file with **.key** extension and inside start with:

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Algorithm:`RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding`

```
  // encrypting session key using public key
         public static String encryptSessionKey_PublicKey(String data) throws  NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, CertificateException, FileNotFoundException {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("D:\\cedge_uat\\STAR_cedgenetbanking_in.cer");
            CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) f.generateCertificate(fin);
            PublicKey publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
            String encodedData = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherData);
            return encodedData;
        }
```

But how to decrypt the above string using `.keyfile`.

Please help me.

I've searched many solution but unable to get proper one.

```
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question, which invalidates one or more answers, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users with edit privileges should proactively revert such changes. Thus, I have reverted your edit. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Answer (score 1):

I had this lying around - hope it'll do the job for you:

```
private static byte[] getByteArrayFromHex(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

public static ArrayList<String> readLines(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        // Print the content on the console
        res.add(strLine);
        }
        //Close the input stream
        br.close();
        in.close();
        fis.close();
        return res;
}

public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String privateKeyHex, String algorithm) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        byte[] encodedPrivateKey = new byte[privateKeyHex.length()];
        encodedPrivateKey = getByteArrayFromHex(privateKeyHex);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
                encodedPrivateKey);
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
        return privateKey;
    }

public static PrivateKey loadKeyPrivateHexStr(String path, String privateKeyFile,String algorithm)
            throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException {
        String hexPrivateKey = readLines(path + privateKeyFile).get(0); 
        PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(hexPrivateKey, algorithm);
        return  privateKey;
    }

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] inpBytes, Key key, String xform) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(xform);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(inpBytes);
    }

private static String decrypt(String inpHexStr, Key key, String xform) throws Exception {
        return new String(decrypt(getByteArrayFromHex(inpHexStr), key, xform));
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, Exception { 
    String xform = "RSA/NONE/PKCS1PADDING";
    PrivateKey prvk = loadKeyPrivateHexStr("C:\\","/mykeyfile.key" ,"RSA")
    String enc = ""; //encrypted string
    ......
    //load encrypeted string into enc
    ......   
    String dec = decrypt(enc, prvk, xform);
    System.out.println(dec);
}
```

Comment: Are you for sure your code will help because it is a PKCS#1 encoded **RSA** Private Key and not a Java-type PRIVATE KEY ?

Comment: sorry, I want to encrypt the message with private key. using sha256RSA algorithm but as now getting error. Please help me how to acheive this

Comment: @prathibha. I thought that you are looking for decryption ... are there problems with encryption too?

Comment: @prathibha.: Your code says "Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");" and that is **SIGNATURE** but not **ENCRYPTION** ??

Comment: @prathibha. have you just change the whole question ? don't do that  ... if you have another question - you post a new one....

Comment: @prathibha. please rollback to your original question - otherwise I will be forced to delete  my answer (cause it answers a different question)

Comment: @MichaelFehr The same session key generated in step 1 (genrated one session key)should be signed by using client’s Private key and convert the same to base64 encoded format
• Algorithm: SHA256withRSA

Comment: @MichaelFehr as per document ,mentioned as signature only for that signature i have to do like above comments. so how i can achieve this

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your question/requirements. As you have a RSA Private Key in use ("BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY") this kind of keys it not directly usable in Java without a) prior converting e.g. with OpenSSL - or - b) using libraries that are been able to read the keys in Java. Please make a research on your own as I believe there is a lot of lack in knowledge when things like digital signatures, sorry.